# How to handle unavailable JSON property while passing to another method

Tags: java, json

Beginner in Java working on parsing JSON array with nested objects into simplified JSON array using the below code.
It is working fine if the JSON element property is having a proper value or null, but if the property is not present it is throwing Null pointer exception, please help me how to handle this inside the data parsing method..

```
import com.google.gson.*;

public class DataParser {

    public static JsonArray parseData(JsonArray data) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonArray dataArray = new JsonArray();
        for (JsonElement dataObj : data) {
            
            JsonObject obj = dataObj.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonObject finalDataObj = new JsonObject();            
            JsonObject fieldsObj = obj.getAsJsonObject("fields");
            finalDataObj.add("key", obj.get("key"));
            finalIssueObj.addProperty("cityName", getValue(fieldsObj.get("cityName")));
            finalIssueObj.addProperty("category", getValue(fieldsObj.get("category")));

            dataArray.add(finalDataObj);
        }

        return dataArray;
    }
    
     public static String getValue(JsonElement fieldValue){
         if(fieldValue.isJsonNull()) {
            return "";
        }
        else{
            return fieldValue.getAsString();
        }
    }
```

}

Input:

```
[{"key":"1232", "fields": {cityName":"Hyderabad","updated":"2023-05-31","category":"Dining"}},
{"key":"1233", "fields": {cityName":null,"updated":"2023-05-31","category":null}},
{"key":"1234", "fields": {cityName":"Delhi","updated":"2023-04-31"}}]
```

Output:

```
[{"key" : "1232", "cityName": "Hyderabad", "category" : "Dining"}, 
{"key" : "1233", "cityName": "", "category" : ""},
{"key" : "1234", "cityName": "Delhi", "category" : ""} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{"key":"1234", "fields": {cityName":"Delhi","updated":"2023-04-31"}
```

This record doesnt have `category` , so while executing

```
 getValue(fieldsObj.get("category"))
```

`fieldsObj.get("category")` will return `null` ,  and pass `null` to method `getValue(JsonElement fieldValue)` so then `fieldValue` will be null and `fieldValue.isJsonNull()` will throw Null pointer exception. You need to judge `null` before use it

```
public static String getValue(JsonElement fieldValue){
     if(fieldValue==null || fieldValue.isJsonNull()) {
        return "";
    }
    else{
        return fieldValue.getAsString();
    }
}
```